# How can I compare an array of values in Java to find the largest value in the list?

Tags: java

So, I need to check all the values of a list and return the largest of the bunch (listsize is a variable that I've previously declared, which is the size of the list). This is proving to be harder than it seems. This always gives me the value in a specific location in the list... what is wrong?

```
package act9;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Act9 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String[] listnames = null;
            int[] listgrades = null;
            int size = 0;   
            System.out.println("How many students in your class? ");
            try {
            size = input.nextInt();
                if(size<=30) {
                    listnames = new String[size+1];
                    listgrades = new int[size+1];
                }
                else if(size>30) {
                    System.out.println("The maximum class size is 30, didn't you know?");
                }
            }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("This needs to be a number, please. Jesus, how dense.");
            System.exit(0);
            }
            try {
            for(int c=0; c<size; c++) {
                System.out.println("Give the [first] name of a student:");
                listnames[c] = input.next();
                System.out.println("What was their final grade?");
                listgrades[c] = input.nextInt();
            }
            }catch (Exception f) {
            
                System.out.println("Did you correctly type the name and grade? you're so dumb I think I'll stop the program right here.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        System.out.println("Out of your group of " + size + "students, this were their scores;");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("name    |     grade");
        System.out.println("____________________________________");
        for(int c2=0; c2<size; c2++) {
            System.out.println(listnames[c2] + "    |     " + listgrades[c2]);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        
        }
        int temp = 1;
        int d = 0;
        for (d=0 ; d<size; d++) {
        }
         if(Math.max(listgrades[d],listgrades[temp])==listgrades[d]) {
             temp = d;
         }
         else {
             //temp=temp. That's what nothingness means
             
         }
         System.out.println("Your student with the highest grade is " + listnames[temp] + " with a grade of " + listgrades[temp] + " points. Well Done.");
        }
    
    }
```

This Is the full code, but it is slightly convoluted with stuff (the idea is that there ahd to be a classroom blah blah blah. Grades, whatever. It's a sort of assignment that I can't get my head around)

Comment: Can you use java-8? Also your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Do you realize that there is no code in the body of your `for` loop?

Comment: Let me try to upload a code that DOES compile. Wait a second... it will take a while because my code is long and contains MANY useless things

Comment: Even with the edit, the `for (d=0;` loop doesn't have a body. The `if(Math.max` is outside the `for` loop.

Comment: Add tags so we know the language and the problem context. Also look harder next time. This is an ez question and you've clearly just given up and come here to get the answer without any real effort involved besides staring at your paper being confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.sort` to sort your list

provided your list is an array of ints you can do something like this:

```
Arrays.sort(listarray);
int highest = listarray[listarray.length - 1];

System.out.println("Your highest number is " + highest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int array[] = [3,6,2], largestNumber = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    if(i == 0) {
        largestNumber = array[i];
    }
    int newNumber = array[i];
    if(largestNumber < newNumber) {
        largestNumber = newNumber;
    }
}
System.out.println(largestNumber);
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Assume listGrades is an array to store a list of grades.
You can try this to find the largest value in the list

```
    int[] listGrades = new int[]{1,3,5,10,6,2};
    int largest = listGrades[0]; //assume the first element is the largest
    for(int index=1; index < listGrades.length; index++)
    {
        if(listGrades[index]>largest) //if there is any element in the list larger than the current one
              largest = listGrades[index]; //replace it
         else
                  ;//do nothing
     }

     System.out.println("Largest value in the list is : " + largest);
```

Hopefully this will clarify your question on finding the largest value in a list.